# How to recalculate the height of a cell after asynchronous image load? (using autolayout)

Tags: ios, uitableview, autolayout

So I have a tableview with cells that contain a different number of images...I use auto-layout to display them in a horizontal list in the cell. Here's a snippet:

```
NSArray *subviews = @[self.imageView1, self.imageView2, self.imageView3, self.imageView4, self.imageView5];
[self.imageView1 autoMatchDimension:ALDimensionHeight toDimension:ALDimensionWidth ofView:self.imageView1];

[subviews autoMatchViewsDimension:ALDimensionHeight];
[subviews autoDistributeViewsAlongAxis:ALAxisHorizontal withFixedSpacing:10.0f insetSpacing:NO alignment:NSLayoutFormatAlignAllCenterY];

[self.imageView1 autoPinEdge:ALEdgeTop toEdge:ALEdgeBottom ofView:self.titleLabel withOffset:kLabelVerticalInsets relation:NSLayoutRelationEqual];

[self.imageView1 autoPinEdgeToSuperviewEdge:ALEdgeLeading withInset:kLabelHorizontalInsets];
[self.imageView1 autoPinEdgeToSuperviewEdge:ALEdgeBottom withInset:kLabelVerticalInsets];
```

I load the images with:

```
loadImageForURLString:
```

I want the cell to wrap my label and my images once the images load. How do I do this using auto-layout?

Thanks!

Comment: I haven't seen these `auto` methods yet, but you could create a custom UITableViewCell subclass and have reference to the imageView's height constraint. Then change it once the image loads. (Done through reloading the cell).